# How is chvt(1) implemented in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

Because the GNU code is bloated and nonstandard, and also as an experiment, I began reimplementing some programs in GNU coreutils, such as `cp`, `ls`, etc...

I came across `chvt(1)`. However, when I look online or in the man pages, there is no indication of what function is used. The coreutils source code is too spaghettified with `#define`'s and underscores for me to even begin to understand, so I couldn't look there either.

What library function (or system call) is used to change the foreground VT? I am using Linux.

Comment: Check out `strace`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

Comment: `VT_ACTIVATE` - `man console_ioctl`